# What does the Lorentz force depends on? Is it the current or the voltage in case of Magnetohydrodynamic Propulsion?

Tags: electromagnetism, propulsion

I recently came across a paper named ["Magnetohydrodynamic Propulsion for the Classroom"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ecdd/8b264ded93b039c4df4411eb2b6bce169f90.pdf) by Gabriel I. Font and Scott C. Dudley. In that they explain about an experiment in which they try to propel a board using magnetohydrodynamic.

In their paper, they stated with the equation $F = qv \times B$, and later they came to two conclusions:
$$F=L\text{I}\times B$$

> Where,
>
> **F** is the force 
> **I** is current 
> **L** is the *distance between two electrodes* 
> **B** the magnetic field.

$$F=ILB= \begin{pmatrix}
    V_{\text{battery}}\ell W\\
  \hline
    H\rho\\
  \end{pmatrix}H\ B$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
    V_{\text{battery}}\ell W\\
  \hline
   \rho\\
  \end{pmatrix} B $$

> Where;
>
> **$F$** is the force
> **$V_{\text{battery}}$** is the voltage between the electrodes
> **$\ell$** and **$W$** is the length and width of the electrodes,
> ***$\rho$*** is the resistivity of the material
> **$B$** is the magnetic field.

[image]

The question is if I connect a power supply of $200$ volts and $10mA$ (neglecting the fact that $200$ volts can  start electrolysis) and other parameters are as follows:

> $L =1$cm 
> $B =1$ Tesla  
> $\ell = 5$ cm 
> $W =2$ cm  
> $\rho= 0.22 \Omega $

Substituting these in equation 1 gives me an $$F= 0.01 \times 0.010 \times 1= 0.001 N$$

But when substituting values in the second equation the Force $F$ is $$\frac{((200 \times 0.05\times 0.02) \times 1)}{0.22}= 0.909 \approx 1 N$$

How can these two equations give different answers for the same situation?

Comment: Permalink: https://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1804659